# understanding javascript expression resolution

Tags: javascript

I read in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

> An expression is any valid unit of code that resolves to a value.

Is the aforementioned value what is returned in the console next to `<` ?

[image]

Also how come `x = 7` resolves to the value `7`, and `var x = 7` resolves to the value `undefined` since the two commands are doing the same thing : assigning the value 7 to the variable x of the global namespace ?

Comment: `var x = 7` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: if you assign a variable, you have no output. Thus, the output is undefined.

Comment: Having `var` statements return anything is meaningless, as you can't use the  `var` keyword anywhere where you would be able to use the returned value. Regular assignment does however always return the value.